# Custom minimize button do not call MouseLeave event

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple stage with `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` (no default buttons). 
Therefore I tried to create my own custom buttons, represented each by an `ImageView` with the next events activated: `setOnMouseEntered`, `setOnMouseExited` and of course `setOnMouseClicked`.

Problem is for the **Minmized** Button. Is a simple implementation like below

```
ImageView.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
    stage.setIconified(true);
});
```

Lets imagine that my ImageView is a **White** rectangle. On mouse enter event, it changes its color into **Black**. On mouse exit, it is going back to White color.

When the `ImageView` is clicked, the window will be minimized, everything perfectly workable until now.

Problem is when the application is restored (maximized), the Minimized custom button is stuck with color **Black** (the color that represent the button is hovered), instead of **White** (default color when is not focused).

P.S. it seems that everything like `relocate`, `setImage` etc. inside the `onMouseClicked` handler is cut by the the `setInconified(true);`

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you for your time of reading this.

**Updates to clear a bit the question**

[The normal print-screen image (when it is not hovered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrt6X.png)

[The hover print-screen (when it is hovered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpM86.png)

As you can observe, everything works perfectly. In the moment when "-" button (minimize button) is pressed, when the application is restored, it will remain stuck in hover mode, until the mouse cursor will hover again the button (then everything comes back to normal). Sadly neither CSS approach or event listeners on image view dose not seems to solve this issue.

**Update code loaded**

This is a simple one source file with just a button that call minimize

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class Main extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            this.stage = stage;
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

            stage.setFullScreen(true);
            stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");

            createScene(stage);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createScene(Stage stage) {
        Pane layer = new Pane();
        layer.setPickOnBounds(false);

        scene = new Scene(layer, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("application/application.css");

        layer.getChildren().add(buildMinimizeImage());
    }

    private ImageView buildMinimizeImage() {
        ImageView imv = new ImageView();
        int width = 43 ;
        int height = 36;

        imv.setId("myImage");

        imv.setFitWidth(width);
        imv.setFitHeight(height);

        imv.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            stage.setIconified(true);
        });

        imv.relocate(100, 100);

        return imv;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And the application.css is very simple as well

```
#myImage
{
    -fx-image: url("minimize.png");
}
#myImage:hover
{
    -fx-image: url("minimizeIn.png");
}
```

Issue is reproducible on Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10. I do not think is an OS problem

**RESOLVED**

Please find enclose the Harry Mitchel solution (thank you one more time for it). It is perfectly workable.

If you want to fix the code from above I by adding the setOnMousePressed event.

```
imv.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
    imv.setImage(image);
});
```

Comment: You need to post all the stuff related to the button - event handlers, any css. If you have event handlers in other Nodes that is within the button's routing tree, also include that.

Comment: Do you also have this problem when you are using other ways to minimize the window? (For instance windows button + down in windows 10). My application will show the 'hovered' state when I minimize it, but after restoring it will immediately repaint. Possibly this is due to a bug in javafx? Are you testing with the latest JVM?

Comment: I have javafx version 8.0.111-b14 , java 8, and running on ubuntu 14.04 . Hover state is showing as well, but the problem is that when I restore it, for me repaint is not triggered.

Comment: In that case you should test if the basic javafx hovers do work correctly, for instance normal buttons. This might be a javafx bug.

Comment: I tried to use Button instead of ImageView. Same effect. I will mount a PC with Windows 10 on it, to see if it is the same behavior.

Comment: Just tried it out on a Windows 10 machine. The issue is exactly the same. It becomes a bit frustrating. Can you please post me a functional code of a custom minimized button that is working for you?

Comment: @user2805346 unfortunately I don't have a minimize button, I was just using the Windows keyboard shortcuts while hovering a normal button.

Comment: @Thirler thank you so much for your response. I understand. Would it be way too much if I might ask you to try a very very simple basic custom minimize implementation. I still think that i miss something, I cannot possibly think that oracle did miss such an obvious case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the maximized property of the Stage class. Inside the changed() method, set the ImageView's image.

```
stage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        //Display the desired icon here.
    }
});
```

Here is a custom minimize button. You provide the two images and the stage as parameters. When the mouse is not over the button, it will show the image referenced in the constructor's first parameter. When the mouse is over the button, it will show the image referenced in the constructor's second parameter. When you click the image the stage will be minimized.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MinimizeButton extends Button {
    /**
     * 
     * @param img the image when the button is NOT selected
     * @param imgHover the image when button is selected
     * @param stage the stage that will be minimized
     */
    public MinimizeButton(Image img, Image imgHover, Stage stage) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
        this.setGraphic(imgView);
        this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
            imgView.setImage(imgHover);
        });

        this.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
            imgView.setImage(img);
        });

        this.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            stage.setIconified(true);
            imgView.setImage(img);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is an example app that uses the MinimizeButton class.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class CustomMinimize extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        Image imgWhite = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("imgWhite.png"));  //your image here
        Image imgGreen = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("imgGreen.png"));  //your hover image here
        MinimizeButton btnMinimize = new MinimizeButton(imgWhite, imgGreen, stage);
        btnMinimize.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        btnMinimize.setPrefSize(50, 50);
        Button btnExit = new Button("X");
        btnExit.setMinSize(50,50);
        btnExit.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.exit(0);
        });
        btnExit.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(2);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(btnMinimize, btnExit);

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(hBox);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hBox, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(hBox, 5.0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Tried this as well :( No good ... As I ask others, I would be so greatful if you can give me a workable sample of a custom minimize button. I really think is that of my version or wrong approach ...

Comment: Thank you so so much. Your solution is workable and is exactly what I was looking for. I do not know yet the reason why this is working and why others do not, due to the fact that i just scan very fast and try it out. Later i might came back with a reply why was not working. Overall thank you very much for this clean and workable solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. In the MinimizeButton class, in the ActionEvent I switch the button's hover image back to the original image. That's the difference. I love JavaFX and want to see it used more.

Comment: Hey Harry your example is working and is valid, due to the fact that you extended the Button in order to do the minimize (which is great). My ImageView has the setOnMouseClicked a bit bugy. In order to solve this I tricked it as well with 
     
     imv.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
      imv.setImage(image);
        });

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear (not that it is very unclear though), so I will attempt to solve your problem.

I am assuming that your color change is done through `ImageView.setOnMouseEntered()` and `ImageView.setOnMouseExited()`. If this is so, you should instead use CSS.

```
.myImageView
{
    -fx-image: url("my_white_image.png");
}
.myImageView:hovered
{
    -fx-image: url("my_black_image.png");
}
```

For the things in your "PS" section, I couldn't understand, so I would not be able to give any advice on that.

Comment: Hey Jai, thank you for the reply. Sadly the issue still persuade even with css. I am still stuck in hover mode, after maximize again. Even if in the "setOnMouseClicked" handler I am changing for example the button position (then call the <setIconified(false)> ), the update (reallocation) will be taken in consideration just after I hover again the minimized button (in the old position).

Comment: The button stays frozen, until it is hovered and all the updates before minimized are taken in consideration.